# Processing a large dataset - row operations & column operations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[Teams_and_seasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqG7E.jpg)

My output should looks like this:
[Teams_and_seasons_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjUYk.jpg)

The dataset lists the points from different seasons for 8 teams. The code should sort the dataset in descending order by points and then concatenate the teams and points and show the results in a row.

I wrote a vba macro in Excel, but when the number of rows hit 250K, Excel crawled to snail speed and took 2 hrs. I would like to change this processing to Python to make it run faster. However, I am not an expert in Python Numpy or Pandas to do this processing, and I am looking for help to achieve this.

Thanks for your help. The dataset is available in a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post a solution, but I'm not sure what kind of time increase you will get. You'll have to test it. Also, I'm sure there are more succinct solutions using `pandas` or something. This solution is just in python.

The essential strategy is just to sort each row and keep track of which team is associated with which score.

Also, if you are brand new to python, you can read about list comprehensions if the code doesn't make sense. They are one line for loops.
Example:

```
a = [i for i in range(5)] #-> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [[i for i in range(3)] for j in range(2)] #->  [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

```
# parse the csv file - there is also a csv library you can look at
def parseCSV(fname):
    # extract the rows from the file
    lines = None 
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]

    # uncomment to view the data structure to ensure its consistent  
    for line in lines:
        #print(line, sep=" ")
        continue

    # extract the teams and remove from lines
    teams = lines[0]
    lines = lines[1:]

    # not part of output, but if you need the seasons 
    seasons = [line[0] for line in lines]

    # extract the data - parse it to integer 
    scores = [[int(li) for li in line[1:]] for line in lines]

    # return the values 
    return teams, seasons, scores

def sortRow(row, teams):
    #associated each score with the team that scored it
    row = [(team_index, score) for team_index, score in enumerate(row)]

    # sort the row based on score (x[1]) - lambda x: x is an inline function 
    # where x is the input (in this case (team_index, score) and x[1] tells 
    # python to sort by the score value (since its at position 1)
    # the [::-1] at the end reverse the array since we want descending order
    sorted_row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]
    
    # transform index and value to string format requested in output
    return [f'{teams[team_index]}-{score}' for team_index, score in sorted_row] 


# tie it all together 
formatted_data = []
teams, seasons, score_matrix = parseCSV('scores.csv')
for row in score_matrix:
    formatted_row = sortRow(row, teams)
    formatted_data.append(formatted_row)

# save to csv file all at once - to add to existing file replace 'w' with 'a' 
with open('sorted_scores.csv', 'w') as out:
    for row in formatted_data:
        out.write(f'{",".join(row).strip()}\n')
```

And this was the scores.csv file

```
Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4, Team5, Team6, Team7, Team8
Season1, 22, 12, 12, 22, 14, 18, 28, 10 
Season2, 14, 30, 16, 16, 18, 14, 16, 24
Season3, 24, 24, 16, 16, 28, 30, 16, 16
Season4, 20, 20, 14, 24, 12, 18, 20, 22
Season5, 30, 28, 10, 16, 24, 14, 14, 18
```

Comment: I will check this out. The code looks much elegant than what I have in Excel

Comment: hello @sin tribu, the code worked as expected. The run time was significantly less than Excel VBA. The only challenge I have now is: if I want to include comments column in the scores.csv. How would I do that? I tried something like this: final_data = list(zip(formatted_data, comments)); I got the comments from parseCSV just like other columns. The problem was when writing to csv the formatted_data Python complained that 'list was not expected'

Comment: Glad it sped things up, I wasn't sure. I'm not sure I understand, if not, add an edit to your question including the code you have. But I suspect if you're saying ```for row in final_data: out.write(row)``` is throwing error, it's because when you ```zip(formatted_rows, comments)```, ```row``` is now in form ```[list, str]```. Print row to verify. If so, you can say ```for row, comment in final_data: ``` I'll let you figure out how to write those two to strings (HINT: out.write takes a string as input). Post some code if I didn't understand correctly. Cheers!